# left side Attribute filter with checkboxes , Magento2.2.6

Tags: magento2, attributes, frontend, layered-navigation, checkbox

I am using Magento2.2.6 Our requirement is attribute filter with checkbox display on left side layer navigation inside.Not page reload Ajax using filtering.If anyone idea and if this functionality working code please share with me.If have you free extension anyone please share it
,for example i need this type of

[image]

Comment: try this: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-ajax-layered-navigation

Comment: also this one :)  https://github.com/acharrex/magento2-extension-ajax-layered-navigation

Comment: I need to multiple selected checkbox in left side layer navigation